# Get server templates related to each document in composite templates

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I need to get the templateId related to each document in a composite templates envelope.

I am already calling the Envelope: get API to fetch recipient, tabs and documents under the envelope right after the Envelope: create API call. I cannot use another API call to EnvelopeTemplates API to get the templateId and documentId mapping because of the envelope polling limits.

Is there any way to include the templateId for each document in the Envelope: get API itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polling limits apply only if you are making a GET request to the same resource (i.e. GET Envelope to the same envelope) in the span of 15 minutes. EnvelopeTemplates and Envelope are two separate resources. You can use the [EnvelopeTemplates:listByDocument](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopetemplates/listbydocument/) to get the template Id associated with a particular document.

If you are querying the same template that you are using to create an envelope, wouldn't it be better to cache the templateId since you would need it right after?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was confused because the API guidelines mention that the limits apply for any list or get method for any object. I didn't realize that it applied individually to each resource. https://developers.docusign.com/platform/api-guidelines/

I would prefer EnvelopeTemplate: list because it requires only one API call per envelope.

I already am caching the templateId, but there is no way to connect the templateId with the documents (retrieved from Envelope: get) unless we do an additional API call to EnvelopeTemplate: list.